# Select lines from two files containing matching strings

Tags: pattern-matching, match, text-processing

Suppose I have two files A and B. Contents of A :

```
foo1 foo2
bar1 bar3
```

Content of B :

```
bar2 bar3
foo3 foo4
```

How do I select the second line from A, and the first line from B? There is no search string. I need to select the lines containing all possible common strings.

Please note that I am NOT looking for matching lines from two different files. The desired lines are not identical, but contain a common string.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you building some application or what? If true then in which language?

Comment: No, I have two lists - locations of audio files and their transcripts (not sharing similar directory structure). But there are always more audio files than the transcripts, so I am looking at selecting only those which have a corresponding transcripts.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. One of your paragraphs states that "[t]here is no search string". Then your second-to-last paragraph says that the desired lines contain "the query string".  What is your definition of "search string", and how does it differ from "query string"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Edited the 'query string' to 'common string'. The solution must check for all possible common strings

Comment: I am also in the need of same. Someone give some way

Comment: @Nivetha Since I was dealing with file locations, the names alone (without path) can be extracted using 'dirname' in bash. Then I could find the matching lines from the new files containing only the file names.. It's not a solution to the problem, but a workaround

Comment: @ManojKumar - Thanks. But here in my case the file names list itself will be huge. So this will not workout in my case. Anyway thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in [TXR Lisp](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr common-word-lines.tl file1 file2
bar1 bar3
bar2 bar3
```

Code in `common-word-lines.tl`:

```
(defun hash-file-words (name)
  (with-stream (s (record-adapter #/\s+/ (open-file name "r")))
    (hash-list (get-lines s) :equal-based)))

(defun lines-containing-words-in-both-hashes (name hash1 hash2)
  (let ((s (open-file name "r")))
    (mappend*
      (op if [some (tok-str @1 #/\S+/) (andf hash1 hash2)]
        (list @1))
      (get-lines s))))

(tree-case *args*
  ((file1 file2 extra . junk) (throwf 'error "too many arguments"));
  ((file1 file2)
   (let ((hash1 (hash-file-words file1))
         (hash2 (hash-file-words file2)))
     (put-lines (lines-containing-words-in-both-hashes file1 hash1 hash2))
     (put-lines (lines-containing-words-in-both-hashes file2 hash1 hash2))))
  (else (throwf 'error "insufficient arguments")))
```

This makes two passes through the files. In the first pass, we build a hash of all the space-separated words in both files. In the second pass, we print each line from each file which contains at least one word that occurs in both hashes.

Lazy list processing is used, so although it may look like we are reading the entire file at once, that isn't in fact the case. [`get-lines`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-00B65D06) returns a lazy list.  In `hash-file-words`, the file is actually being read as the `hash-list` function is marching down the lazy list that is passed into it. In `lines-containing-words-in-both-hashes`, [`mappend*`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02A03B1C) is used, which lazily filters a list and appends the pieces.

What is `(andf hash1 hash2)`? Firstly, [`andf`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02A03B1C) is a combinator. It takes multiple arguments which are all functions, and returns a function which is a short-circuiting AND combination of these functions. `(andf a b c)` yields a function which will pass its arguments to function `a`. If that returns`nil` (false), it stops and returns `nil`. Otherwise it passes its arguments to `b`, and the same logic is applied. If it gets all the way to `c`, then whatever value is returned by `c` is returned. Secondly, although `hash1` and `hash2` are hash tables, they can be used as functions in TXR Lisp. A hash table behaves as a one-argument function which looks up its argument in the hash table, and returns the corresponding value, or else `nil`. Thus `(andf hash1 hash2)` simply uses the AND combinator to build a function which returns true if its argument exists in both hash tables (associated with a non-`nil` value).

Thus, `[some (tok-str @1 #/\S+/) (andf hash1 hash2)]` means "tokenize the line into words, and report if some of them are in both hashes". `@1` is the implicit argument of the anonymous function generated by the `(op ...)` macro. That function is called for every element of the list produced by `(get-lines)`; i.e. every line of the file. So `@1` successively denotes each line.

More generalized version: shorter, and handles two or more arguments:

```
(defun hash-file-words (name)
  (with-stream (s (record-adapter #/\s+/ (open-file name "r")))
    (hash-list (get-lines s) :equal-based)))

(defun lines-containing-words-in-all-hashes (name hashes)
  (let ((s (open-file name "r")))
    (mappend*
      (op if [some (tok-str @1 #/\S+/) (andf . hashes)]
        (list @1))
      (get-lines s))))

(unless *args*
  (put-line `specify one or more files`)
  (exit 1))

(let ((word-hashes [mapcar hash-file-words *args*]))
  (each ((file *args*))
    (put-lines (lines-containing-words-in-all-hashes file word-hashes))))
```